# spring security - is there an way to get session registry inside my application (without explicilty customizing the concurrentFilter)

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security, httpsession

I was referring to [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?110686-SessionRegistry-getAllPrincipals) thread, and in the second last post by `Rob Winch` (Spring Security Lead), he mentions that we can have access to the sessionRegisty :

```
<session-management>
  <concurrency-control session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry"/>
</session-management>
```

Therefore, I register the `HttpSessionEventPublisher` filter in `web.xml` and specify the above setting in my `<http>` section. I **DON'T** add this :

```
<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

and in my class, I inject an instance of sessionRegistry like this :

```
@Autowired
private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry
```

This is how I am trying to find out the sessions for a user:

```
List<SessionInformation> userSessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(username,false);
        for (SessionInformation userSession : userSessions){
            userSession.expireNow();
        }
```

The principal is the username of the user. Upon debugging, the `sessionRegistry` variable's `principals` and `sessionids` variables are empty.
Am I doing anything wrong here, or are the steps mentioned by [krams's blog](http://krams915.blogspot.in/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-querying.html), the only way to do this ?

Comment: @Xaerxess - The sessionRegistry variable that is inserted has no session ids or authentication in it. Note that I haven't defined the sessionRegistry bean explicitly

Comment: Can you post the code of class accessing `sessionRegistry`? How do you check if the registry empty?

Comment: Are there any principals in registry? See my edit.

Comment: Yes.. the current user's principal is present now... I don't know why it wasn't working before, but there weren't any authentication objects in the sessionRegistry object before.. just glad its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for comment, so I answer.

1. Turn Spring Security debugging on (add to `log4j.properties` line `log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG`). This should be standard procedure in such problems, as debugging prints many handy information that can show were the problem is.
2. Can you debug if `public void registerNewSession(String sessionId, Object principal)` method inside `SessionRegistryImpl` is called after logging? If not that means `HttpSessionEventPublisher` is not set up correctly.
3. You use `@Autowired private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;` in your class, dont't you?
4. **EDIT**: Can you check if there are any principals in registry?

   ```
   List<Object> userSessions = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
   ```

   where `Object`s are principals instances you use.

Comment: This is marked as an answer, but what's the answer? I'd like to see if I can use the SessionRegistry without enabling concurrency-control.

Comment: @Eyal, did you found solution?

Comment: Nope. I ended up dropping the idea of using the SessionRegistry and writing my own HttpSessionListener extension instead.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can autowire sessionRegistry. Nothing is wrong. I used it to track `SessionInformation` and registered sessions for `UserPrincipal`

Comment: But is what I have configured sufficient for that ?

Comment: if you are using mixed configuration(like above xml and annotations), then it is correct. Autowire sessionfactory with interface as : `@Autowired private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;`. Because on your provided link, autowired bean in class is `SessionRegistryImpl`. Your xml configuartion for sessionfactory is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It only worked for me if I changed session-registry-alias to session-registry-ref,and then defined the default impl:

```
<security:session-management>
    <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="10" session-registry-ref="sessionRegistry"/>
</security:session-management>

 <bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends which version of spring security you use.

In Spring Security **3.0** it is enough to have the configuration as follows:

```
<security:session-management>
    <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1"/>
</security:session-management>
```

Because internally there is used class **ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy** which invokes **registerNewSession** on **sessionRegistry** object.

In Spring Security **3.2** it is different and you have to use more verbose configuration. There is an example in the [Spring Security reference doc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrent-sessions)
The most important part to have **sessionRegistry** filled with data is the following:

```
<beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
  <beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:list>
      <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
        <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
      </beans:bean>
      <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
      </beans:bean>
    </beans:list>
  </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
    class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

The registration of a new session in **sessionRegistry** is performed in **RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy** class.

Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: `there is used class ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy` internally in what class?